# Best way to edit android shell files /system/bin/ in windows

Tags: android, linux, editor

what is simplest way to edit android shell files in "/system/bin/ on windows without installing linux or Cygwin or something like these?

Comment: OMG! .sh file is not "android script files". It is a shell script file, which works only on Linux. You can't run it on windows without Cygwin

Comment: thanks for you mention alexander i modified my question

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out:

Atom Editor - http://www.atom.io

SublimeText - http://www.sublimetext.com/3

or even Notepad ++ - https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

All of these are able to Open/Edit .sh filetype

Comment: Did you read his question? Your answer is not relative to it.

Comment: How isn't my answer relative to his question?

Comment: Autumn already edited his question. I thought that he want to run .sh file on windows. But he want to edit it. It confused me. I'm sorry for this.

Comment: but notepad++ cannot open it, is it needs some plugins?

Comment: Hey, I have just opened a .sh file in both Atom.io and Notepad++ with no problems?

Comment: sorry for wrong question, not (.sh) files i mean shell files exists in /system/bin/ in android , these files doesnt have any suffixes , files like "busybox" , "am" , 
atrace"

Answer (score 0):

.sh file is shell script file you can edit it in any plain text editor like notepadd++ or notepadd but you can run them only on linux